# Почему параметр print выводится в консоль, но не выводится в файл?

Tags: python, бот, telegram

Нужно, чтобы код бота выводил данные в консоль и в файл. Однако результат print(message.from_user.id, cfg.ADMIN_ID) выводится в консоль, но не записывается в файл. В файле появляется строка 'message.from_user.id', но не значение, как в консоли.
Почему?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    print(message.from_user.id, cfg.ADMIN_ID)
    file = open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    file.write('message.from_user.id')
    file.close()
```

Comment: Потому что вы записываете в файл именно строку, а не значение выражения. Кавычки вас не смущают?

Comment: замените `file.write('message.from_user.id')` на `file.write(str(message.from_user.id))`

Comment: Смущают, но если без них, то вообще ничего в файл не записывается, а в консоли появляется TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @ZxNuClear Получилось, спасибо!

Comment: @Andrey ну если получилось тогда добавьте ответ самому себе.